# Custom url in iis for windows authentication is asking login credentials

Tags: windows, authentication, url, iis, model-view-controller

I have a mvc application which is hosted on iis with some port number running successfully with windows authentication. Now my client asked to use the user friendly url like [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) to browse the application.  I have added the hostname in binding with default port number 80. Also added the url in hosts file with 127.0.0.1 and [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com), now it is asking the username and password to login, even if I give the correct credentials also, after 3 attempts it is saying user not allowed to view this. In code level I have added authentication mode=windows and deny users=?, inside web.config file. And enabled both anonymous and windows authentication in iis. Please help how to resolve this without changing the settings, because other apps also running on the same server. Thanks in advance. Suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use Windows Authentication and access the web application without entering an additional username and password. Try going to Providers in the Windows Authentication feature, make sure NTLM is the only provider selected and remove Negotiate, it will stop showing the login prompt. Also, what you describe is that when you provide the correct credentials, the user is not allowed to view this, is there any detailed error information in the log?

Comment: Yes, in providers section I have given NTLM only.  Still asking the login. Error log is like "User is not authorised to view this directory". But without using user friendly url, its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only configure the user-friendly URL in the local hosts file (path: %windir%\system32\drivers\etc), you can use this domain name to access locally, but you cannot access it from the outside through this domain name, only through IP.

This is because the local etc/hosts file is only used to provide domain name resolution services for the local system. The system you are trying to access the website from outside is not aware of this mapping and cannot resolve the domain name to an IP.

You can use the following methods:

- If you have a DNS server available on your network, you can register
  the name there. (recommend)
- You can add a mapping in the hosts file of each system that will
  access the website.

Comment: Hi @yurongdai , I have added the application in iis of that particular domain only. I just added the url in binding and the same in hosts file, then in iis right click on application and click on browse, then it is asking login, even if given correct credentials,  its not accepting and after 3 attempts,  it is saying user dont have access to view this.

Comment: If you do not use a user-friendly URL, will a login prompt box pop up asking you to enter your username and password when you access the website?

Comment: No, if I dont use user friendly url, it is not asking me to enter username and password.  Its just taking the windows user as I have written c# code to take the current username and I am validating it with database employee data.

Comment: Have you repeatedly received this windows security popup: [image](https://imgur.com/a/HCrN75v)

Comment: Yes @YurongDai , its getting 3times, then its getting error. I followed the below link and succeeded but it only getting in one server among multiple servers in the same network. Donno how to fix this to access in all servers in a single network.   Followed 1st method in this link anwer. 
 https://serverfault.com/questions/485006/why-cant-i-log-in-to-a-windows-protected-iis-7-5-directory-on-the-server/485011#485011